# Using *ngIf with a dynamic variable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I was following this example : [Angular2.io Example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html).

When `selectedHero` is `null` the `div` element should not be displayed, that works fine, but when I select a hero using click event and `selectedHero` is not `null`, the `div` element is still not displayed.

I have tried using `boolean` variable too but after changing click event the variable is updated but the `div` element is still not displayed.

```html
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor='let hero of myHeroes' (click)="onSel(hero)">
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div><label>Name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name" />
  </div>
```

**This is the component code :**

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of heroes!';
  selectedHero: Hero;
  HeroesList: Hero[] = [//can also be used to display 
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
  ];

  onSel(shero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = shero;
    // alert(this.selectedHero.name);
  }
}

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: What is the code for setting `selectedHero`?

Comment: onSel(shero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = shero;
    // alert(this.selectedHero.name);
  } , this is the click event

Comment: what does the code for the template click event look like?

Comment: Recheck the code , i have updated it

Comment: Everything looks good so far. Is the top section of HTML part of the AppComponent Template or another component/directive?

Comment: belongs to same component i.e AppComponent

Comment: everything looks ok - can you recreate the problem in plunkr?

Comment: do i need any import to use ngIF directive ?

Comment: Please check the answer and tell me the reason for this, why ul element was to be within div , else the code was not working

Comment: are you able to get alert(this.selectedHero.name); to execute? everything seems fine to me. check your console.

Answer (score 1):

You missing some imports from`@angular/core` where `ngIf` is defined

see [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SlnDnt5HByDzugnK3Rsd?p=preview)

The reason that `ngIf` is not working is that created content is not valid html.

Comment: the only import i have is import { Component } from '@angular/core';
do i need any import to use ngIF directive ?

Comment: tried these also ! still not working ............import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: Thanks, The problem was in template , the list that was displayed was to be within <div> , else the code was not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in template, ul element was to be within div , else the code was not working , let me know the reason for this, Thanks.

```
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor='let hero of myHeroes' (click)="onSel(hero)">
          <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
          <div><label>Name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name" />
  </div>
</div>
```